# How to use AWS Cognito in a Blazor application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, blazor, amazon-cognito, blazor-webassembly

I am developing Blazor client app to AWS Gateway->AWS Lambda.
Are any Blazor examples how to use AWS Cognito authentication?
I have found how to use AWS Cognito in ASP.NET 6 but cannot find Blazor samples.